# Python Variables references not working

Tags: python-3.x

Python 3.4.4,
Windows 8.1

I having some trouble to handle variables in python. I have a program that stores reference dictionaries. This is stored in a static.py file. When I pull the reference dictionary from another .py file it is changing the original reference.

```
static.py File

dictionary_a = {'a': 'The sky is blue and {}.', 'b': 'Second sentence'}
```

---

```
Main.py file

from static.py file import dictionary_a


dictionary_b = dictionary_a

c = dictionary_b['a'].format('Yellow')
print (c)
print (dictionary_a['a'])

output
>> 'The sky is blue and Yellow.'
>> 'The sky is blue and Yellow.'
```

I would like to reference the dictionary from the static.py but leave the original variable intact. So the ideal output will be.

```
>> 'The sky is blue and Yellow.'
>> 'The sky is blue and {}.'
```

Comment: `dictionary_a = {'The sky is blue and {}.'}` is not a `dict` but a `set`. It may not matter here, but it's confusingly named.

Comment: The above code can't work, since you're calling `format` on a `set`, which leads to an `AttributeError`; it definitely does not give the output you show.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. When you try to create a copy of a dictionary you need to do it explicitly in python as using dictionary_b = dictionary_a refers to the same dictionary.

To create a copy the correct way will be:

dictionary_b = dict(dictionary_a)

or

dictionary_b = dictionary_a.copy()

Comment: This might be true but your original code did not do what you say it did, so it is hard to help in general, e.g. dictionary_b['a'].format('Yellow') has no side effect on the dictionary so printing out the `dictionary_a['a']` would still be `'The sky is blue and {}.'`.